# Change column in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

My application contains `ListView` with files that i am handling and have 3 columns: file name, length and status.
Inside my for loop i am handling file after file and want in this case to change the status column from **wait** which is the value at the beginning to **in process**.
is it possible to change one column ?

lvFiles is my ListView

```
for (int i = 0; i < lvFiles.Items.Count; i++)
{
    //here i am do things with my file
}
```

Here i am adding files into my ListView:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { new FileInfo(filePath).Name, duration, "Waiting" });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SubItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems.aspx) property of `ListViewItem`:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in lvFiles.Items)
    item.SubItems[2].Text = "Waiting";
```

Comment: +1 Much better Answer lazyberezovsky I forgot about SubItems...Grrrr..LOL

Comment: @DJKRAZE thanks! working with listView is like solving a puzzle :)

Comment: I know but that's the first thing I thought of because of how he wanted the for loop, he didn't specify initially what column he wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this if you know the specific Column for example Address would be 
colString[2] you can do a single line

```
string[] colString = new string{ "Starting", "Paused", "Waiting" };
int colIndex = 0;
foreach (ColumnHeader lstViewCol in lvFiles.Columns)
{
  lstViewCol.Text = colString[colIndex];
  colIndex++;
}
```

for single column you stated you wanted the 3rd column then you could something like this

```
lvFiles.Colunns[2] = "waiting";
```

Comment: What other conditions are you looking to change the Column based on something..? if so that could be added in the foreach loop using an if(){} statement.. you need to provide more information to your original question otherwise others will respond the same way that I did.. for example what Column Header are you wanting to change..? 1, 2, or all 3 ...?

Comment: inside the for loop i only want to change the status column for the current file [i]

Comment: i want to chanhe column no. 3